# Android: Issue with Placing two Toggle Buttons one below another using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, user-interface, button, toggle, android-relativelayout

I am having strange issue with Toggle Buttons. I want to Center Them horizontally and place them One below another using Relative Layout.

However no matter what I do - they always end up side by side

Any Ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg7"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView android:id="@+id/spacer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:text=" ">
</TextView>


<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spacer"
    android:paddingTop="5dip"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ShowNotification"
            android:onClick="switchNotification"
            android:textOn="Show Notification"
            android:layout_width="220dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_above="@+id/UpdateLog"
            android:textOff="No Notification"/>

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/UpdateLog"
            android:layout_width="220dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:onClick="swtichLogging"
            android:textOn="Log"
            android:textOff="Don't Log"/>
</TableRow>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure its because you have a `TableRow` that is not inside of a `TableLayout` What are you trying to do anyway with the spacer? use padding or margins instead. So far as I can tell, this is how your code should look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg7"
    android:layout_margintop="65dp"
    >
    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ShowNotification"
        android:onClick="switchNotification"
        android:textOn="Show Notification"
        android:layout_width="220dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:textOff="No Notification"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/UpdateLog"
        android:layout_width="220dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:onClick="swtichLogging"
        android:textOn="Log"
        android:textOff="Don't Log"
        android:below="@id/ShowNotification"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting each button to FILL_PARENT.